# Importing “google/protobuf/descriptor.proto” in golang

Tags: go, swagger, protocol-buffers

I'm using [custom options](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto?hl=cs#options) to define swagger annotations for my proto service definition.

There is already an implementation of this [swagger annotations](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/master/protoc-gen-swagger/options/annotations.proto) so I just need to import this implementation on my .proto service definition

```
import "protoc-gen-swagger/options/annotations.proto";
...
```

The problem is that this library has a dependency of **google/protobuf/descriptor.proto** and this descriptor library was created on **proto2** specification(this library is from the protocolbuffers/protobuf [project](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto))

```
syntax = "proto2";
package google.protobuf;
```

so when I tried to build the proto for php I receive the error:

```
-php_out: google/protobuf/descriptor.proto: Can only generate PHP code 
for proto3 .proto files. Please add 'syntax = "proto3";' to the top of 
your .proto file.
```

Does anyone know where I can find the proto definition of **google/protobuf/descriptor.proto** on proto buffers version 3? o how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The generator library protoc-gen-swagger only supports protobuf version 3. Your error will keep keep coming up unless you changed `proto2` to `proto3`. Please read https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/usage.html.

Also it's clearly stated on your error message:

> -php_out: google/protobuf/descriptor.proto: **Can only generate PHP code 
>   for proto3 .proto files**. Please add 'syntax = "proto3";' to the top of 
>   your .proto file.

Comment: Yes, I'm using proto3 on my annotation definitions, but protoc-gen-swagger has a dependency to google/protobuf/descriptor.proto(this library is from protocolbuffers/protobuf/ google project) and I had only found that library on proto2 [version](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto), so I cannot generate the code for php. I don't know where to get this library google/protobuf/descriptor.proto on proto3.

Comment: I had a similar issue, the file `google/protobuf/descriptor.proto` won't come installed from any dependency of go protobuf. Instead is being referenced to the original src proto types of google, which are here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto and will be installed by the compiler.

Check the `descriptor.proto` file exists in `usr/include/google/protobuf/` or `usr/local/include/google/protobuf/`. Probably is missing.